# does powershell have a hard breakpoint keyword

Tags: powershell, debugging

Been searching around and not able to find an answer to whether or not powershell has a hard breakpoint solution. Something like javascript `debugger;` and python `breakpoint()` and vb `Stop`.

Instead i have to author dummy lines inside if statements that i can assign soft breakpoints to.

```
if ($item.Value -eq "some large iteration case i need to debug through") { 
    $i = "using to enable soft breakpoint on specific case for debugging purposes as powershell doesn't appear to have have hard breakpoint expression"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Set-PSBreakpoint and enable/disable-psbreakpoint

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint?view=powershell-7

https://ss64.com/ps/enable-psbreakpoint.html

Comment: Thanks for response.  I saw those cmdlet options and tested `Set-PSBreakpoint -Script myscript.ps1 -Variable myvariable` as well `Set-PSBreakpoint -Script myscript.ps1 -Line <line #>` followed by `Get-PSBreakpoint -Script myscript.ps1` to confirm it was set and then ran script and it does stop on the variable assignment or line number. I also used `Remove-PSBreakpoint -Id <breakpoint #>` for removing them.  I guess it's a usable solution for hard breakpoint just not quite the in code keyword based approach i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Download the PowerShell ISE, or use Visual Studio with the PowerShell extension.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have both powershell ISE and visual studio code which both support powershell soft breakpoints.  Was looking for a keyword that enabled hard breakpoints such that you get prompted to attach a debugger when running the script not launched by a debugging ide directly.